# can you force a record to be added in one model when a record is created in another in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have two classes:  Class and Position.

```
# Reference Table Class
class Class(models.Model):
    unit_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    unit_description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.unit_name


# Reference Table Position
class Position(models.Model):
    Position_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    Position_description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    Max_count = models.IntegerField()
    unit_class = models.ManyToManyField(Class, through='ClassPosition')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.Position_name
```

When a Class is created (not updated), I want to force a record to be made in the Position table.  How do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save) signal, or by [overriding the model's `save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) method.

In `post_save()` signal method, you can use the `created` argument to find out whether it's new object or updated object. In overridden `save()` method, that would be done with the condition: `if not self.pk:`.

Comment: I recommend you to override Save method in Class. Do not use signals in this use case!